# How to hide/mask passwords in Fastlane logs?

Tags: logging, passwords, fastlane

I was looking for a way to safely handle passwords in Fastlane and found that there is a built in method for entering passwords `UI.password`:

```
lane :enter_password do
    password = UI.password 'Password: '
    sh "echo Your password is #{password}"
end
```

This works great, but when you are using the password, it's printed in plain text in the logs:

```
------------------------------------------------------
--- Step: echo 'Your password is tAM5RdCRxD3e3TU' ---
------------------------------------------------------
$ echo 'Your password is tAM5RdCRxD3e3TU'
▸ Your password is tAM5RdCRxD3e3TU
```

Ideally, the output should be something like this:

```
------------------------------------------------------
--- Step: echo 'Your password is *****' ---
------------------------------------------------------
$ echo 'Your password is *****'
▸ Your password is *****
```

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, not without adding this functionality to Fastlane.

But what you can do is to pass `log:false` to `sh` for the command that uses the password:

```
lane :enter_password do
    password = UI.password 'Password: '
    sh "echo Your password is #{password}", log:false
end
```

This causes Fastlane to only output:

```
---------------------------
--- Step: shell command ---
---------------------------
```

The problem with this is that it suppresses everything, including error messages, which makes it very difficult to debug problems when the command fails. A workaround for this is to put the password in an environment variable, like so:

```
lane :enter_password do
    ENV['PASSWORD'] = UI.password 'Password: '
    sh 'echo Your password is $PASSWORD'
end
```

The output of that will be:

```
---------------------------------------------
--- Step: echo Your password is $PASSWORD ---
---------------------------------------------
$ echo Your password is $PASSWORD
▸ Your password is tAM5RdCRxD3e3TU
```

That means that as long as your command doesn't print the password to the logs, you will get all the output, without revealing the password.

Comment: In the example, the password is still output. I don't see how this solves the problem

Comment: @abc123 `echo` prints stuff, so if you deliberately print the password, the password will be in the output. In this example, I use `echo` for clarity, but in the real lane you would use something else, like `./encrypt.sh -p $PASSWORD file`, in which case the password would not be printed.